# Delay on notifications from Facebook and Skype app on Lollipop

Tags: notifications, 5.0-lollipop

I use a Google Nexus 5 with Android Lollipop, the latest version. I use both Facebook messenger, Skype, and Whatsapp as message services. All three of those often have a delay (up to 30 minutes sometimes!) in giving me a notification that I got a new message.

Is there any way to fix this? It is very annoying.

Comment: It seems there is a problem with your network connection, as I didn't experience that on Nexus 4 running Lollipop 5.0.1. However, without additional info, it's almost impossible for us to know the cause and fix the issue: Does the issue occur on other apps with push notification? Have you checked the quality of the connection on Android?

Comment: Well it has happened on multiple WiFi networks, The connection was almost always good. I'm not sure if it has happened on 3G. What additional information would you require?